# Permissions required to move file to different directory in Unix/Linux

Tags: linux, unix, file-permissions, mv

I would like clarification on the permissions required, in order to move a file A from directory B to directory C (the command would be "mv B/A C/A", I think), with name unchanged.

Am I correct to think that the following are required?

1. The user/group doing the move must have write permission for directory B (or B must have permission flag set to allow all users/groups to write it)

   The user/group doing the move must have write permission for directory C (or C must have permission flag set to allow all users/groups to write it)

   The user/group doing the move must have write permission for file A (or A must have permission flag set to allow all users/groups to write it)

Thank you.

Comment: This is a good question, but I think it belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: But here we also have a tag `file-permissions`, so read it as "what conditions do I have to check before I let my script perform a `mv` of the specified kind" ;-)

Comment: Sorry I did not know there is another site for UNIX questions. I will bear this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Actually, moving a file is either a rename of a file on a single file system or creating a copy and deleting the original (typically only done if the move is a migration from one file system to another).

In either case you need **execute** *and* of course **write** permissions to the target directory and the source directory.  However, for a mere *rename* (and moving from one directory to another can be just that) on a single file system you do *not* need **any** permissions on the file itself.  It can be cleared of all permissions and still you can move (rename) it (as long as you have **write** and **execute** permissions for the directories).

For a real copy (as it is needed when you move the file to a different file system), you need **read** permissions on the file itself.  **No write** permissions on the original are necessary, as deletion of a file is not writing to it (but to the directory it is in).

Comment: Thank you. Just to make sure that I understood you correctly: to move the file (with/without renames) within the same file system, no permission needed on the file; to move the file (with/without renames) to a different file system, r permission needed on the file; in both cases, w and x permissions on the directories are required.

Comment: Yes, you summarized correctly.  Just one thing:  One _one_ file system renaming and moving is exactly the same thing; "moving" is just renaming the directory-entry's full path (i. e. the part stating its parent directories) instead of just the directory-entry's base name (the part after the last slash).  It is done via the system call `rename(2)`; tools like `mv` test whether using this is possible and only if it is not (different file systems or unsupported by the file system) fall back to copy-and-delete.

Comment: Ah, and another implicitness I forgot to mention:  You also need to have **execute** permissions on _all_ parent directories of the source and the target directory.  Maybe you want to have a look at the system call `access(2)` which can be used for checks on such things.

Comment: @Alfe can you explain why **write** / **execute** are needed on the source directory "for a real copy"? In other words, if I can **read** the target, can't I already "copy" it's contents into memory?

Comment: Execute and write permissions are needed on the target directory for creating a new directory entry there.  They are needed on the source directory for removing a directory entry there (the topic here is moving a file and on the directory level this is what moving means).  For creating a copy alone, only read permissions on the source file and execute permissions on all its (parent) directories are needed.  But read my answer carefully: moving a file on one file system does not necessarily require reading it because no copy is made.

Comment: Hello, adding a comment about the case where A is a directory might be nice. 'w' permission is needed on A to update A/'..': https://stackoverflow.com/q/55133284/3936601

Comment: Whoa.  The question luckily says explicit that A is a file.  I say "luckily" because if A is a directory, that's a whole different case, so I would rather give a completely specialized answer for this case.  The answer I gave here will probably a _part_ of that other answer then.  But in short:  Moving a directory _on the same file system_ is like moving a file on the same file system (and needs the same permissions).  Moving a directory across file systems is creating it on the target, copying the complete contents (recursively) from the source to the target, then removing the original.

Comment: (continued) But this copying over can be rather complex, e. g. if the directory itself doesn't allow writing into it.  Then you have to create it first with _set_ write permissions and _revoke_ these after you recreated everything which is _inside_ it, etc.  As I said, that will be a rather complex thing I won't put into my existing answer or into a comment.