# why can't I `mv` a directory without extra write permissions

Tags: linux, unix, permissions

My understanding of permissions has been broken today.

```
evaben@evaben /t/test> ll
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x  4 evaben evaben 4.0K Mar 13 12:44 ./
drwxrwxrwt 19 root   root   4.0K Mar 13 12:43 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 evaben evaben 4.0K Mar 13 12:44 mine/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root   4.0K Mar 13 12:44 theirs/
```

I own the CWD, and `mine`, and have write permission on both.

```
evaben@evaben /t/test> mv mine theirs/
mv: cannot move 'mine' to 'theirs/mine': Permission denied
```

Of course I cannot move my directory into theirs; I do not have write permission in `theirs`.

```
evaben@evaben /t/test [1]> mv theirs/ mine/
mv: cannot move 'theirs/' to 'mine/theirs': Permission denied
```

Why can't I move `theirs` into `mine`? I can write the CWD, AND the dest (`mine`). I am not modifying `theirs` in any way.

```
evaben@evaben /t/test [1]> sudo chmod o+w theirs/
evaben@evaben /t/test> mv theirs/ mine/
(works)
```

I can mv if I have write permission on theirs.

The wikipedia explanation states:

> When set for a directory, this (write) permission grants the ability
>   to modify entries in the directory, which includes creating files,
>   deleting files, and renaming files.

Arch wiki states similar, which seems to reinforce my (clearly wrong) understanding.

To further cloud my brain, it works as I expect for a file:

```
evaben@evaben /t/test> ll
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x  3 evaben evaben 4.0K Mar 13 13:04 ./
drwxrwxrwt 19 root   root   4.0K Mar 13 12:43 ../
drwxr-xr-x  3 evaben evaben 4.0K Mar 13 13:03 mine/
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      0 Mar 13 13:04 their_file
evaben@evaben /t/test> mv their_file mine/
(worked)
```

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions)
[archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes)

EDIT:

I have tried to use rename(2) directly.

```
rename("theirs", "mine");
```

Works IFF `mine` is empty. - effectively mine is replaced my theirs. If mine has files; `ENOTEMPTY 39 Directory not empty`.

```
rename("theirs", "mine/theirs");
```

Gives `EACCES 13 Permission denied`. Which is both what I want to do and what `mv` gives - so apparently not a bug in `mv` (still a bug in my understanding).

Comment: Have you tried to change the owner?  `sudo chown -R evaben:evaben root-directory`

Comment: Thanks @PabloDarde, I am not trying to do a thing, I am trying to understand why things don't work how they are explained.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.  Also see [Permissions required to move file to different directory in Unix/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20948946/608639) and friends. Asked and answered many times before across the web...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the rename(2) man page has the explanation:

```
ERRORS
       EACCES Write permission is denied for the directory containing oldpath or newpath, or, search per‐
              mission  is  denied for one of the directories in the path prefix of oldpath or newpath, or
              oldpath is a directory and does not  allow  write  permission  (needed  to  update  the  ..
              entry).  (See also path_resolution(7).)
```

So apparently in order to move `theirs` into `mine`, you need to have permissions to update the `..` link on `theirs`.

Comment: Great answer, TIL unix file hierarchy is doubly-linked

Answer (score -1):

> "I am not modifying `theirs` in any way."

Not quite correct. Part of the `mv` process is deleting the file from its original location. Which means you need write permission for that original location, which you don't have. Try using `cp` instead.

Comment: I have a rebuttal, I CAN `rm their_file` - deleting a file is modifying the containing FOLDER, not the file. I can also `rmdir their_folder`, so it is not a different rule for folders.

Comment: Apologies, my answer was unclear. You need write permission for the "original location" (which is the containing folder/directory) Edited to clarify. Thanks!